# How to remove apostrophe from text?

Tags: python, document

This is not a duplicate question, I've searched and implemented the various answers found in stackoverflow, without any success.

I'm converting a .docx file to plain text in python, but then, the print on the CMD shows funny characters for the character " ' ". (i.e. *canΓÇÖt*). Below are my codes:

```
if file.endswith('.docx'):
        docx = zipfile.ZipFile(fullpath)
        content = docx.read('word/document.xml')
        cleaned = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>','',content)
        text=unescape(cleaned)
        newtext = text.replace("'", " ")
        print newtext
```

Answers from stackoverflow led me to putting "text=unescape(cleaned)" and "text.replace("'", " ")", but without any successful results.

How do I remove apostrophe from string variables? Or better still, how do I ensure that the apostrophes appear correctly?

Comment: Give a example please..

Comment: Sounds like it's not an apostrophe, it's a single quote mark. Especially if converting from `docx`. Here's a good way to tell, do `ord("'")` (a single apostrophe), then do `ord("your_character")` (the single "apostrophe" copy/pasted from your document)

Comment: @Sayakiss what do you mean by example? Example of the funny characters? I've given up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're not looking at `'some_text_here'` you're looking at `‘some_text_here’`. That is to say, single curly (or "smart") quotes.

Do this:

```
if file.endswith('.docx'):
    ...
    cleaned = re.sub('<(.|\n)*?>','',content)
    cleaner = string.translate(cleaned, None, ["‘","’"])
    # python3 has to use:
    # # cleaner = cleaned.translate(str.maketrans({'‘':'','’':''}))
```

For reference:

```
>>> ord("‘") # left single smart quote
# 8216
>>> ord("’") # right single smart quote
# 8217
>>> ord("'") # single apostrophe
# 39
```

Comment: Oh it works! Thank you!
BTW, for other people looking at this thread for answers, I've found another one, credits to @Adam Smith :
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   #Add this to allow your program to decode MSDOC's single smart quotes.
Then, the only changes I've made to my above code is this line:
newtext = text.replace("’", "'")
Output will be all the smart quotes are replaced with single apostrophe. Which is what I exactly want!